# Mapping between and image and its re-sized version

Tags: image, image-processing, thumbnails, image-resizing

I am looking for a certain formula that can be used to obtain the mapping of pixel positions between an image and its re-sized version. For example, I'd like to know what are the present pixels from original image in the re-sized version using the formula. i.e, in row say i only pixels from column j_m, J_n,.... are present in the re-sized version and the rest are eliminated. I am talking about the re-sizing which is just scaling without any aspect ratio preserving or window-averaging.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know the scaling factor ?

Comment: When I look at the tags, It actually seems to be the simple case :)

Comment: @mmgp yes I know the scaling factor

Answer (score 0):

After reading all the comments I'm confused by what exactly you want to achieve, so you might want to excuse my possible naïveness in this answer.

The basics: to scale an image (a signal, a function, anything at all) you apply the standard scaling matrix. This site doesn't allow proper LaTeX inlining, so make some effort to understand the following representation. The scaling matrix, for a 2D image, is given by S = [sx 0; 0 sy]. Since we are not interested in performing rotations and translations at same time, there isn't much point in moving this representation to homogeneous coordinates. The matrix is simple, very simple. So, for example, to scale x by a factor of 6, and y by a factor of 4, S = [6 0; 0 4]. Applying this matrix to every point gives your scaled image. Following is a direct example of this application, original image and scaled one by 6x, 4y:

[image]    [image]

As you see, there are a lot of blank points in the upscaled star. That is why actually the upscaling is performed through the inverse scaling matrix. The inverse of the mentioned matrix is trivially obtained, and corresponds to S-1 = [1/sx 0; 0 1/sy]. The advantage of doing this is that the interpolation is, basically, an obligatory step to perform the inverse transformation, i.e. you have a discrete domain and you get real positions, to handle that you perform some kind of interpolation. Following is the simplest possible interpolation: nearest neighbor by truncating the real value to an integer. The scaling factor is, again, 6x and 4y, but done in the inverse form:

[image]

It should be clear that you can't exactly recover a scaled image (even if you know the scaling factors) because the scaling process is free to do anything in the interpolation step. But you can simply apply directly the scaling, with inversed factors, in the scaled image to get an approximation of the unscaled image. In this example we get the following image, which happens to be exactly the same as the original one.

[image]

If it helps, here is very simple Python code that exemplifies what was discussed.

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(sys.argv[1]) # Assumed to be grayscale.
width, height = img.size
scale_x, scale_y = (6, 4)
imo = img.load()

# Upscale directly.
full_img = Image.new('L', (width * scale_x, height * scale_y), 'white')
im = full_img.load()
for x in xrange(width):
    for y in xrange(height):
        im[x * scale_x, y * scale_y] = imo[x, y]
full_img.save(sys.argv[2])

# Upscale by inverse transform.
full_img = Image.new('L', (width * scale_x, height * scale_y), 'white')
im = full_img.load()
for x in xrange(width * scale_x):
    for y in xrange(height * scale_y):
        im[x, y] = imo[int(x / float(scale_x)), int(y /
            float(scale_y))]
full_img.save(sys.argv[3])

# Downscale the previous upscaled image.
downscaled = Image.new('L', (width, height), 'white')
im2 = downscaled.load()
for x in xrange(width * scale_x):
    for y in xrange(height * scale_y):
        im2[x/scale_x, y/scale_y] = im[x, y]
downscaled.save(sys.argv[4])
```

Comment: thank. Imagine that I have the big star white image. Then, I shuffle the pixel positions on that one to get an image which is not similar to the white star image. Then, I am going to re-scale the shuffled one to the smaller size. Then by applying the reverse shuffling, how I am able to get an image which is equal to applying the resizing to the original white star without shuffling? I hope you get what I am saying.

Comment: Your inputs are the big star, `f`, and the scaling factors (`sx`, `sy`). Now let's say you exchanged pixel `a` with pixel `b` in `f`. Then you downscale `f` by `sx`, `sy`. After this transformation, pixel `a` ended up in pixel `b` position, and vice-versa. Now you want to "unshuffle" `a` with `b`. Is this your question/doubt ? If you know how the shuffling was done in `f`, and if the points are transformed without interpolation, then you simply unshuffle taking into account the inverse scale factors. This should be clear after understanding the transformations presented in the answer.

Comment: I tried to implement it but the result I get is not the correct re-sized version. I guess either I miss something or the mapping does not work properly

Comment: There isn't much more I can do for that, I already provided code to the resizing which doesn't use any form of library.